# convert from physical path to virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this function that gets the fileData as a byte array and a file path. The error I am getting is when it tries to set the fileInfo in the code bewlo. It says 'Physical Path given, Virtual Path expected'

```
 public override void WriteBinaryStorage(byte[] fileData, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create directory if not exists.
            System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath)); //when it gets to this line the error is caught
            if (!fileInfo.Directory.Exists)
            {
                fileInfo.Directory.Create();
            }

            // Write the binary content.
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath), fileData);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When debugging it, is providing the filePath as `"E:\\WEBS\\webapp\\default\\images\\mains\\myimage.jpg"` . And the error message is

```
'E:/WEBS/webapp/default/images/mains/myimage.jpg' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.
```

Also, what it is triggering this to happen is the following call

```
properties.ResizeImage(imageName, Configurations.ConfigSettings.MaxImageSize, Server.MapPath(Configurations.EnvironmentConfig.LargeImagePath));
```

Comment: May I know why the negative votes I am new to C#. Please be considerate

Comment: Do you understand what `MapPath` does and what your code is trying to do?

Comment: This is existing code, i did not write it.. My understanding is that MapPath is a function that will take the virtual path and translate it into the servers path?, but again i am new and i maybe overlooking the obvious. Without being rude, I came to this forum to ask a question I am not sure about. No need to down vote.. I imagine this is what forums are for no? Other wise I am just going to go profile by profile and do a bunch of negative votes just because of the heck of it

Comment: Exactly.  Once you call it once, it makes no sense to call it again on that result.  The code and error message are clear enough that you should have been able to realize that, IMHO.

Comment: Okay thank you, it ismuch clearer now.. Appreciate your patiennce

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you already have a physical path, it doesn't make sense to call `Server.MapPath`.

You're calling `MapPath` twice.

Comment: Thank you, so instead of using Server.MapPath, what should I replace that line of code for?

Comment: Sometimes it's just so trivial to spot stupid errors.

Answer (score 5):

Working:

```
    string[] filesPath = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/txtPath/"));        
    foreach (string path in filesPath)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);      //This Is Working
       string LastAcceTime = fi.LastWriteTime; //Return Correct Value
    }
```

Not Working:

```
    string[] filesPath = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/txtPath/"));        
    foreach (string path in filesPath)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(path));  //This Is Worng
       string LastAcceTime = fi.LastWriteTime;             //Return 1/1/1601 
    }
```

Dont use `Server.Mappath` twice

Answer (score 2):

I take it that your project is located at:

```
E:\WEBS\\webapp\
```

You should try and use relative references to your images e.g.

```
..\default\images\mains\myimage.jpg
```