# How to combine address for web or file system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, path

In C# I must create a method that receives as parameters webPath or fileSystemPath plus a file name. Consider that this method is going to be called from a asp.net and also from a windows form project.
This are the cases I assume that could be, and the code I wrote so far:

```
string webPath1 = "//someaddress";
string webPath2 = "//someaddress/";
string fsPath1 = @"\\somefolder";
string fsPath2 = @"\\somefolder\";
string filename = "somefilename.txt";

string WebPathFileName1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(webPath1, filename);
string WebPathFileName2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(webPath2, filename);
string s1 = Path.GetFullPath(WebPathFileName1);

string FsPathFileName1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(fsPath1, filename);
string FsPathFileName2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(fsPath2, filename);
string s2 = Path.GetFullPath(FsPathFileName1);
```

If you test the code you will see that WebPathFileName1 returns "`//someaddress\\somefilename.txt`" but I should response with "`//someaddress//somefilename.txt`".

The input path could end or not with `\` 
What other methods could I use to combine paths? Thanks.

I may come with more details from my project leader as I know. The idea is that, as I said, this method will be called from 2 kind of projects. So it should compose a web path or a files system path.

Comment: may be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961704/how-do-i-join-two-paths-in-c

Comment: thanks for your answer but that treats only folder paths not web too, that is why my request is different. thanks.

Comment: That is physical path and not the virtual path for that you need to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171275/convert-from-physical-path-to-virtual-path

Comment: For webpath, use VirtualPathUtility.Combine