# Error when create a folder by code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Member Register aspx page.

```
ACCOUNT(user,pass,mail,privilege)
```

When a user is registerd sucessfully, if the `privilege == "lecturer"` --> a  folder is created which `folder's name= user`.

Take a look at my code below:

```
 if(privilege=="lecturer")
        {
            string path = this.Server.MapPath("~/Lecturer/"); // path="D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\"
            string targetPath = path + @"\";           
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(targetPath+newuser));

        }
```

It has an error: `'D:/C#Projects/website/Lecturer/david' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.` Why???

I really want to create a david folder in Lecturer folder. Help???

Comment: You're calling MapPath twice.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171275/convert-from-physical-path-to-virtual-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `Server.MapPath` again as you have already converted the virtual path to physical path.

*Change*

```
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(targetPath+newuser));
```

*To*

```
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath+newuser);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a physical path `D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\`, it doesn't make sense to call `Server.MapPath`

You can try this:-

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\C#Projects\website\Lecturer");
```

or simply try this:-

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath+newuser);
```