# Download image via gridview hyperlink giving error c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please note that the images are bind from a folder which is in the solution itself.

[image]

**I know the problem is I should not use the Server.Mappath but can anyone suggest a workaround for this 
Coz using *Directory.GetFiles with Response.TransmitFile is also not working*..**
What should i do to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert from physical path to virtual path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171275/convert-from-physical-path-to-virtual-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server.MapPath - Physical path given, virtual path expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected)

Comment: please stp marking it as a duplicate.   Response.TransmitFile i tried using Directory.GetFiles but it is not working either. Kindly provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### C# Code

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +        Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
  }
```

Comment: response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
                Or                                                                                                                           Response.WriteFile(filePath);